# How to update a table data in pagination that is part of a view without refreshing the whole page?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, pagedlist

I have one view that displays 3 different tables. So I am using `PagedList` for pagination. How can I rewrite my `GetProduct` method to go to the next page of a table when I click either page number or `>>` ?

Part of the `cshtml` related to `PagedList`

```
 @Html.PagedListPager(Model.Products, page => Url.Action("GetNextProductPage", new { page }))
```

and the action,

```
public ActionResult GetNextProductPage(int?page)
{
   var p=database.GetProducts().ToPagedList(page,10);
   return View("CurrentPage",p);
}
```

The method will update the current page and so it adds view onto view...

Also, how could I return either a `string` or `Json` with `GetNextProductPage` while still able to use `PagedList`?

Comment: what is the target .net framework ?

Comment: the target .net framework is 6

Comment: then use `Virtualize` razor component. read more : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/virtualization?view=aspnetcore-6.0#item-provider-delegate

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, could you answer the questions i made? i don't want to use anything else different than what i am using, pagedlist, ajax, view methods only

Comment: you can use partial view, and render it inside the actual view. Second suggestion is that you need to pass page number and page size to the actual query. currently `GetProducts` will query the whole table and loaded into the memory. Instead of that, just query the table, order the results, and get the desired page.

Comment: great! thank you a lot, I'll go with partial view and review the sql query.